# POST data on Azure Event hub is failing

Tags: azure, post, azure-eventhub

This is regarding Azure Event hub and I am trying to send data using a POST api call from POSTMAN to my Event hub.

Steps I followed:

Created Event Hub,
Generated SAS send token,
Created Consumer group

Now in postman I am struggling to format the correct headers:

request I send:

```
POST:  https://testeventhu.servicebus.windows.net/myhub
```

2 headers :

```
Content-Type : application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8

Authorization:  SharedAccessSignature sig=kjheh/f6SqR8dIW2nRpGUCHuhdshss2KoCKo7Q6ozmY=&se=1571140739&skn=saspolicy&sr=https://testeventhu.servicebus.windows.net/myhub
```

and I get the error as  401 MalformedToken: Failed to parse simple web token

What wrong am I doing in here?the refrence used is from  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/Send-event?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Thanks in advance

Comment: your token should look more something like this `Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=your-namespace.servicebus.windows.net&sig=tYu8qdH563Pc96Lky0SFs5PhbGnljF7mLYQwCZmk9M0%3d&se=1403736877&skn=RootManageSharedAccessKey  
` especially your `sr=` param looks different

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please follow my steps as below:

**1**.After you create your `eventhub namesapce` and `eventhub` instance in azure portal -> in azure portal, nav to your `eventhub namespace` -> Shared access policies, click "Add" button to create a sas policy(here, I just select the Send privilege for sending purpose). The screenshot as below:

[image]

**2**.Generate sas token, I create the sas token via powershell as per this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token#powershell). Here is my powershell code and the returned sas token:

[image]

**3**.In postman:

The request url should like this, remember add `messages` at the end: `https://your_eventhub_namespace.servicebus.windows.net/your_eventhub_instance/messages`

The headers:

Authorization : the sas token from step 2

Content-Type: application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8

Host(optional): your-eventhub-namespace.servicebus.windows.net

the screenshot as below, you can see the returned status code is 201 created:

[image]

And if you don't know how to set the message body, you can see my message in body in postman:

[image]

Please feel free to let me know if you still have any issues.